# How to split a single line, divided by space, into two differente types

Tags: c, file-read

I'm having some trouble finding a solution for splitting a file single line in c.
There is a .txt file like this:

```
9999 m 32
9998 f 20 
9997 o 22 
9996 m 18 
9995 o 45 
9994 f 40 
9993 m 76
```

where, for example, `9994 f 40`, `9994` is an int, `f` a char and `40` another int.

I was trying to use `fgets()` to take the line and separate it afterwards but i'm not finding a way to split the line information in three so i can use them the way it's needed.
There is another function other than `fgets()` that is better for this? Or there is a way to do it with `fgets()`?

Comment: `fgets` is a fine way to read lines.  `strtok` is a good way to split a line into whitespace-separated substrings.  Once you've got your substrings, `atoi` is an okay way to convert any that you think of as numbers (such as your first and third columns) into actual integers.  (And there are better ways than `atoi` to do that, but I think `atoi` is a fine start.)  A web search on `strtok` should find plenty of examples of how to use it.

Comment: There's a better way: Please check out scanf().

Comment: `scanf` is "better" only in a very narrow sense.  It's barely adequate for "toy" programs like this, but completely inadequate for real programs.  Most beginning C programmers are forced to use it, but it's not clear they ever learn anything useful from it.

Comment: i did it with strtok and atoi and it worked. i tried with sscanf too and it was simpler. both worked, thank you all.

Comment: @steve-summit: I agree that it is not for _real_ programs. In fact most experienced C developers use their own or other custom libs. But here scanf() function family is perfect suited for this task which looks like a programming exercise. Well, there's another usage for including stdio.h: Debugging while development. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the text file line by line using `fgets`  and get `int` and `char` values from string using `sscanf` :-

```
char line[30];             // read line by line input from file in this
int a,b;                  
char c; 
while(fgets(line, 30, file) != NULL){    // file is your file pointer
    if(sscanf(line, "%d %c %d", &a, &c, &b) == 3){
        printf("%d %c %d\n", a,c,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: 30 bytes is a pittance. Why not something a little more generous? Also why not [`fscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead of this combination `fgets` -> `sscanf`?

Comment: @tadman using `fgets` + `sscanf` is preferable (if one must use the *scanf family at all) because it can get you around some (though not all) of the crushing problems scanf has if you're trying to do fancier or error-detecting parses.

Comment: @tadman Size can be set anything according to need. I just provided an example there.

Comment: @SteveSummit Admittedly `scanf` in general is problematic in all of its forms. Not sure this two-stage approach saves you from much.